# How to switch out charts on the same canvas with Apache ECharts?

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

Basically what I'm trying to do is have 5 options of graphs each displaying a different set of data (over the same span of time).

[image: Image of what I currently have; dropdown menu with the 5 options]

Here's what I have right now - it's almost everything I want, except the dropdown menu makes it look very messy in my opinion, so I wanted to see if anyone knew of a way using Apache ECharts' library functions to integrate it nicely? I've been looking through the docs for a few hours but I don't think anything fits.

If it helps, the function I'm using right now alongside the dropdown menu is something like:

```js
function change_day_chart(value) {
    if (value == '0') {
        day_chart.setOption(prices, true);
    }
    if (value == '1') {
        day_chart.setOption(buy_volume, true);
    }
    if (value == '2') {
        day_chart.setOption(sell_volume, true);
    }
    if (value == '3') {
        day_chart.setOption(seven_day_buy, true);
    }
    if (value == '4') {
        day_chart.setOption(seven_day_sell, true);
    }
}
```

tl;dr is there any built-in way to switch between datasets in Apache ECharts?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know your data, but this is my code.

the same chart get different parameters,use filter function to deal.

For your reference.

```
 var respon
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/url',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (rets) {
        respon = rets;
        $('#Select').trigger('change');
        //get all data
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});

$('#Select').on('change', function () {
    var Qry = $(this).val(); //Select value
    var res = respon.filter(item => item.Flag == Qry)

    //do something
    var option = {
        //Omit
    };
    Chart.setOption(option,true);
});
```